# Is there an alternative for doing "@str = render_to_string(:json => w) " that doesn't involve rendering?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Heres the fill code:

```
w = JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse(@post.json)
@str = render_to_string(:json => w)
```

`@post.json` is a string of a valid JSON. I want to save the pretty version in a string so I can display it in a view with html.